# NavigationService.Navigate from page constructor

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to use `NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(uri, UriKind.Relative));` in the page constructor. But i get a NullReferenceException. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Please go through the links [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25642/when-is-navigationservice-initialized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25642/when-is-navigationservice-initialized) [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/28/redirecting-an-initial-navigation.aspx](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/28/redirecting-an-initial-navigation.aspx) [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A Page can only get a reference to its NavigationService when Page raises the Loaded event.
If you subscribe to loaded event of the page, then you will get NavigationService instance.

```
public Home()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += (s, e) =>
                           {
                               var ns = NavigationService;
                               ns.Navigate(new Uri("/About", UriKind.Relative));
                           };
    }
```